# If I have a process, and I clone it, is the PID the same?

Tags: linux, exec, fork, pid

Just a quick question, if I clone a process, the PID of the cloned process is the same, yes ? fork() creates a child process where the PID differs, but everything else is the same. Vfork() creates a child process with the same PID. Exec works to change a process currently in execution to something else.

Am I correct in all of these statements ?

Comment: `man 3 fork`, `man 3 vfork` and `man 3 exec` :)

Comment: actually, it's section 2. Not 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite. If you clone a process via fork/exec, or vfork/exec, you will get a new process id. `fork()` will give you the new process with a new process id, and `exec()` replaces that process with a new process, but maintaining the process id.

From [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/vfork.html):

> The vfork() function differs from
>   fork() only in that the child process
>   can share code and data with the
>   calling process (parent process). This
>   speeds cloning activity significantly
>   at a risk to the integrity of the
>   parent process if vfork() is misused.

Answer (score 7):

Neither `fork()` nor `vfork()` keep the same PID although `clone()` *can* in one scenario <sup>(*a)</sup>. They are all different ways to achieve roughly the same end, the creation of a *distinct* child.

`clone()` is like `fork()` but there are many things shared by the two processes and this is often used to enable threading.

`vfork()` is a variant of `clone` in which the parent is halted until the child process exits or executes another program. It's more efficient in those cases since it doesn't involve copying page tables and such. Basically, everything is shared between the two processes for as long as it takes the child to load another program.

Contrast that last option with the normal copy-on-write where memory itself is shared (until one of the processes writes to it) but the page tables that reference that memory are copied. In other words, `vfork()` is even *more* efficient than copy-on-write, at least for the fork-followed-by-immediate-exec use case.

But, in *most* cases, the child has a different process ID to the parent.

---

<sup>*a</sup> Things become tricky when you `clone()` with `CLONE_THREAD`. At that stage, the processes still have different identifiers but what constitutes the PID begins to blur. At the deepest level, the Linux scheduler doesn't care about processes, it schedules threads.

A thread has a thread ID (TID) and a thread group ID (TGID). The TGID is what you get from `getpid()`.

When a thread is cloned *without* `CLONE_THREAD`, it's given a new TID and it also has its TGID set to that value (i.e., a brand new PID).

*With* `CLONE_THREAD`, it's given a new TID but the TGID (hence the reported process ID) remains the same as the parent so they really have the same PID. However, they can distinguish themselves by getting the TID from  `gettid()`.

There's quite a bit of trickery going on there with regard to parent process IDs and delivery of signals (both to the threads within a group and the `SIGCHLD` to the parent), all which can be examined from the [`clone()` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone).

Comment: The CLONE_THREAD flag to clone keeps the visible 'PID' the same.

Comment: You could say that's because CLONE_THREAD clones the thread, not the process as the OP requested.

Comment: The confusion around `CLONE_THREAD` is because the kernel and userspace use different names for the same things, and the same name for two different things.  The userspace `(PID, TID)` pair is called `(TGID, PID)` in kernel space - so `PID` means something different to each.

Answer (score 3):

It deserves some explanation. And it's simple as rain.

Consider this. A program has to do some things at the same time. Say, your program is printing "hello world!", each second, until somebody enters "hello, Mike", then, each second, it prints that string, waiting for John to change that in the future.

How do you write this the standard way? In your program, that basically prints "hello," you must create another branch that is waiting for user input.

You create *two* processes, *one* outputting those strings, and another one, waiting the user input. And, the *only* way to create a new process in UNIX was calling the system call fork(), like this:

```
ret = fork();
if(ret > 0) /* parent, continue waiting */
else /* child */
```

This scheme posed numerous problems. The user enters "Mike" but you have no simple way to pass that string to the parent process so that it'd be able to print that, because +each+ process has its own view of memory that isn't shared with the child.

When the processes are created by fork(), each one receives a *copy* of the memory *existing* at that moment, and if that memory *really changes* later, the mapping that was identical for those memory segments will be chaged *at once* (it's called a copy-on-write mechanism).

Another thingies to share between the child and the parent are, for example, opened file descriptors, descriptors of the shared memory, input/outpue stuff, etc., that also wouldn't survive after fork().

So. The very fork() call *had* to be alleviated, to include shared memory/signals etc. But how? This was the idea behind clone(). That call takes a flag indicating *what exatly* would you share with the child. For example, the memory, the signal handlers, etc. And if you call this with flag=0, this will be *identical* to fork(), up to the args they take. And when POSIX pthreads are created, that flag will reflect the attributes you have indicated in pthread_attr.

From the kernel point of view, there's no difference between the processes created such way, and no special semantics to differentiate the "processess". The kernel does not even know, what that "thread" is, it creates a *new* process, but it simply combines it as belogning to that *process group* that had the parent who called it, taking care what that process may do. So, you have different procesess (that share the same pid) combined in a *process group* each assigned with a different "TID" (that starts from PID of the parent). 
Care to explain that clone() does exactly that. You may pass this *whaterver* you need (as the matter of fact, the old vfork() call will do). Are you going to share memory? Hanlers? You may tune everything, just be sure you don't clash with the pthreads library written right away around this very call.
An important thing, the kernel vesion is quite outrageous, it expects just 2 out of 4 parameters to be passed, the user stack, and options.

Comment: good explanation, only the last paragraph is a bit confusing and has a couple of typos

Answer (score 1):

Since PID is an unique identifier for a process, there's no way to have two distinct process with the same PID.

Comment: Unless the processes are running in a separate PID namespaces (and thus can have the same PID).

Answer (score 0):

Threads (which have the same visible 'pid') are implemented with the `clone()` call. When the flag CLONE_THREAD is supplied then the new process (a 'thread') share the Thread Group Identifier (TGID) with its creator process. `getpid` actually returns the TGID.

See the [clone manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) for more details.

In summary the real PID, as seen by the kernel is always different. The visible PID is the same for threads.

Comment: It's because of historic reasons and that a substitute of all "pid" to "tid" would have made quite some noise in the changelogs, though it would seem necessary given it confuses so many people.