# what's the difference between the threads(and process) in kernel-mode and ones in user-mode?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

my question:

1)In book *modern operating system*, it says the threads and processes can be in kernel mode or user mode, but it does not say clearly what's the difference between them .

2)Why the switch for the kernel-mode threads and process costs more than the switch for user-mode threads and process?

3) now, I am learning Linux,I want to know  how would I create threads and processes in Kernel mode and user mode respectively IN LINUX SYSTEM?

4)In book *modern operating system*, it says that it is possible that process would be in user- mode, but the threads which are created in the user-mode process can be in kernel mode. How would this be possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311402/differences-between-user-and-kernel-modes

Comment: @Anycorn, that question covers the difference between user and kernel modes but it does not cover the difference between user and kernel level scheduling, which I think this question is asking about (at least in parts 1, 2 and 3).

Comment: Do you mean kernel scheduling where the system is aware of the existence of threads and keeps track (Windows) vs. user scheduling where it's done "manually," using a library such as pthread (Linux), or threads executing in kernel mode (drivers; minimal security, minimal protection, hard crashes) vs those executing in user mode (regular processes; normal safety, program crashes)? Parts of your question implies one difference whereas others, another. Also, linux has no threads or one thread per process or many threads per process, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Tanebaum's book. The difference is not clearly explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-mode threads are scheduled in user mode by something in the process, and the process itself is the only thing handled by the kernel scheduler.

That means your *process* gets a certain amount of grunt from the CPU and you have to share it amongst all your user mode threads.

Simple case, you have two processes, one with a single thread and one with a hundred threads.

With a simplistic kernel scheduling policy, the thread in the single-thread process gets 50% of the CPU and each thread in the hundred-thread process gets 0.5% each.

With kernel mode threads, the kernel itself manages your threads and schedules them independently. Using the same simplistic scheduler, each thread would get just a touch under 1% of the CPU grunt (101 threads to share the 100% of CPU).

In terms of why kernel mode switching is more expensive, it probably has to do with the fact that you need to switch to kernel mode to do it. User mode threads do all their stuff in user mode (obviously) so there's no involving the kernel in a thread switch operation.

Under Linux, you create threads (and processes) with the [`clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) call, similar to `fork` but with much finer control over things.

Your final point is a little obtuse. I can't be certain but it's probably talking about user and kernel mode in the sense that one could be executing user code and another could be doing some system call in the kernel (which requires switching to kernel or supervisor mode).

That's not the same as the distinction when talking about the threading support (user or kernel mode support for threading). Without having a copy of the book to hand, I couldn't say definitively, but that'd be my best guess.

Comment: In Linux, the process created by fork() and threads by pthread are all in Kernel mode? I saw some one answered that the schedule of task in Linux is thread level, has nothing to do with process. What do you think? thanks for your answer!

Comment: @city: yes, the Linux kernel schedules threads, not processes (it has kernel mode threading support rather than user mode). There is trickery with thread groups and thread group leaders that make it look to userland like processes exist but it's all smoke and mirrors :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862012/if-i-have-a-process-and-i-clone-it-is-the-pid-the-same/4862050#4862050

Answer (score 4):

There are some terminology problems due more to historical accident than anything else here.

"Thread" usually refers to thread-of-control within a process, and may (does in this case) mean "a task with its own stack, but which shares access to everything not on that stack with other threads in the same protection domain".

"Process" tends to refer to a self-contained "protection domain" which may (and does in this case) have the ability to have multiple threads within it.  Given two processes *P1* and *P2*, the only way for *P1* to affect *P2* (or vice versa) is through some particular defined "communications channel" such as a file, pipe, or socket; via "inter-process" signals like Unix/Linux signals; and so on.

Since threads don't have this kind of barrier between each other, one thread can easily interfere with (corrupt the data used by) another thread.

All of this is *independent of user vs kernel*, with one exception: in "the kernel"—note that there is an implicit assumption here that there is just one kernel—you have access to the entire machine state at all times, and full privileges to do anything.  Hence you can deliberately (or in some cases accidentally) disregard or turn off hardware protection and mess with data "belonging to" someone else.

That mostly covers several possibly-confused items in Q1.  As for Q2, the answer to the question as asked is "it doesn't".  In general, because threads do not involve (as much) protection, it's cheaper to switch from one thread to another: you do not have to tell the hardware (in whatever fashion) that it should no longer allow various kinds of access, since threads *T1* and *T2* have "the same" access.  Switching between processes, however, as with *P1* and *P2*, you "cross a protection barrier", which has some penalty (the actual penalty varies widely with hardware, and to some extent the skills of the OS writers).

It's also worth noting that crossing from user to kernel mode, and vice versa, is *also* crossing a protection domain, which again has some kind of cost.

In Linux, there are a number of ways for user processes to create what amount to threads, including both "POSIX threads" (pthreads) and the `clone` call (details for `clone`, which is extremely flexible, are beyond the scope of this answer).  If you want to write portable code, you should probably stick with pthreads.

Within the Linux kernel, threads are done completely differently, and you will need Linux kernel documentation.

I can't properly answer Q4 since I don't have the book and am not sure what they are referring to here.  My guess is that they mean that whenever any user process-or-thread makes a "system call" (requests some service from the OS), this crosses that user/kernel protection barrier, and it is then up to the kernel to verify that the user code has appropriate privileges for that operation, and then to do that operation.  The part of the kernel that does this is running with kernel-level protections and thus needs to be more careful.

Some hardware (mostly obsolete these days) has (or had) more than just two levels of hardware-provided protection.  On these systems, "user processes" had the least direct privilege, but above those you would find "executive mode", "system mode", and (most privileged) "kernel" or "nucleus" mode.  These were intended to lower the cost of crossing the various protection barriers.  Code running in "executive" did not have full access to everything in the machine, so it could, for instance, just assume that a user-provided address was valid, and try to use it.  If that address was in fact invalid, the exception would rise to the next higher level.  With only two levels—"user", unprivileged; and "kernel", completely-privileged—kernel code must be written very carefully.  However, it's possible to provide "virtual machines" at low cost these days, which pretty much obsoletes the need for multiple hardware levels of protection.  One simply writes a true kernel, then lets it run other things in what they "think" is "kernel mode".  This is what VMware and other "hypervisor" systems do.